# Open Source Filter Analysis and Design Software Tool

Tags: bandwidth

My question is about: What is the best open-source software tool for Design and Analysis of Filters?

Answer (score 1):

You should have a look at [PyFDA](https://github.com/chipmuenk/pyFDA/).
It tries to mimic MATLAB's tools and it is pretty good by itself.

Answer (score 1):

Octave as open source software, a clone of Matlab, is a good tool for Design and Analysis of digital Filters. Compared to Matlab, one has to do all in code, while Matlab deals with nice GUI tools.

Comment: Can you include a link to your suggestion?